# asp.net ajaxtoolkit Custom control extender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Well im trying to write my own custom control extender but i can't get the javascript to work

Here you have a empty class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports AjaxControlToolkit
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls


<Assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("GuiExtensions.PrintButtonBehavior.js", "text/javascript")> 

<Designer(GetType(PrintButtonExtenderDesigner))>
<ClientScriptResource("Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender", "GuiExtensions.PrintButtonBehavior.js")>
<TargetControlType(GetType(IButtonControl))> _
Public Class PrintButtonExtender
    Inherits ExtenderControlBase


End Class
```

And here you have the javascript:

```
Type.registerNamespace('Sys.Extended.UI');
Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender = function (element) {
    Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender.initializeBase(this, [element]);
}

Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
        var element = this.get_element();
        this._clickHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onClick);
        $addHandler(element, "click", this._clickHandler);
    },

    dispose: function () {

        $removeHandler(this.get_element(), "click", this._clickHandler);
        this._clickHandler = null;


        Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    _onClick: function () {
        alert("Test");
        return false;
    }
}

Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender.registerClass('Sys.Extended.UI.PrintButtonExtender', Sys.Extended.UI.BehaviorBase);
```

The problem here is that _onClick is never called when some one is clicking the button i assigned the extender to.. i have verified that "this.get_element();" returns the correct element but i have no luck getting the _onClick function to run.

So far i have hacked this together by looking at the source from codeplex but no success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the type this._onClick

this._clickHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onClick);

to

this._clickHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._clickCallback);

hope this will get results :)

Comment: This worked and im totally confused, do you know why "_onClick" doesn't work?